# Convert from power of ten to power of thousand?

Tags: calculus

How would I do that?

If I have $\frac{10^4}{1000^3}$, what's the next step? Is it to convert the 1000 to 10? How? By $10^3[^2]$? So, 10^9?

Comment: Why would you not convert the power of thousand to a power of ten? Far easier, far simpler, and it's actually an established thing to be done.

Comment: Yes, $1000^3=10^9$ is correct. But I think you have a typo in your post: $10^3[^2]$ should be $10^3[^3]$. (Actually it should be $(10^3)^3$, but that's another question.)

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be 3 to the second power, since a thousand has two more zeros than ten. What's the reason for 10^3[3]?

Comment: I can't convert it first, because the problem is about converting km to cubic km - 1km /1000m, cubed, is 1km^3/1000^3m^3.

Comment: Did you mean $10^{3^2}$? That is correct, but only by accident: your justification "since a thousand has two more zeroes than ten" makes no sense to me. For instance, $1000^4$ is not equal to $10^{4^2}$. (Also, when you reply to my comments, you should have @TonyK somewhere in the text, so that I get notified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write everything as powers of ten, simplify and only then write the expression as a power of a thousand.

First rewrite $1000^3=(10^3)^3=10^9$.

Then use a rule for calculation of exponents: $$\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}.$$

You then have 
$$\frac{10^4}{10^9}=10^{4-9}=10^{-5}.$$

If you want to have this expressed as a power of a thousand, use another rule $$(a^n)^m=a^{nm}\implies 10^{-5}=(10^3)^{\frac{5}{3}}.$$

Comment: Where does the part in brackets come from? "$1000^3=[(10^3)^3]=10^9$" Why is it 3^3?

Comment: @user366783 It comes from $1000=10^3$ and from the second rule I mentioned (I should perhaps have mentioned it earlier), namely $(a^n)^m=a^{nm}$. So it isn't $3^3$ in the exponent, but rather $3\cdot 3$.